# Tried to access files on shared server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to access a file under shared network using Comp B which I am connected to from Comp A and plan to do "reg import" using that file. So far I always get denied and I read that the problem is due to double Hop. Sadly I don't think it is possible for me to change the registry or configuration on Comp B. I have tried to do this so far :

- Create a temporary mapped drive using new-psdrive/net use : still get access denied even when I can see the mapped drive using get-psdrive

> $secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
>
> $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username,
> $secpw) Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Comp B -Credential $cred
> New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\shared_folder"
>
> cd Y:

- Enter PS-Session with credential : still access denied

> ```
> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Comp B -Credential $cred
> cd \\shared_folder\
> ```

- Invoke-command with script block and credential : still access denied

> ```
> invoke-command -Credential $cred -computername Comp B -ScriptBlock {(cd \\shared_folder\),(dir)}
> ```

Comment: Until you show us *how you tried* we are not going to be able to help much.

Comment: I have edit my post. Hope it can help